# Proof verification: lim$(A)=$ lim$(A\setminus\{x\})$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a $T_{1}$-topological space, $x\in X$ and $A\subset X$ be a subset. Show that lim$(A)= $ lim$\left(A\setminus\{x\}\right)$. (I know that the set of limit points is closed, but I want to prove this fact without using closedness)

Now, if $x\notin A$, then $\left(A\setminus\{x\}\right)=A$ and we are done. So, let $x\in A$. For the "$\supset$" part notice that for any $y\in A$ we have $\left(A\setminus\{x,y\}\right)\subset \left(A\setminus\{x\}\right)$, so clearly for every neighborhood $U_{y}$ we can conclude that
\begin{align*} \emptyset\neq U_{y}\cap \left(A\setminus\{x,y\}\right)\subset U_{y}\cap \left(A\setminus\{x\}\right). \end{align*} So $y$ fulfills the definition of being a limit point of $A$.

Now for the "$\subset$" part. Suppose that lim$\left(A\right)$ is not a subset of lim$(A\setminus\{x\})$. So there exists $y\in\text{lim}(A)$, but $y\notin\text{lim}(A\setminus\{x\})$, meaning that for all neighborhoods $U_{y}$ we have that $U_{y}\cap \left(A\setminus\{y\}\right)\neq\emptyset$, but there exists a neighborhood $W_{y}$ such that $W_{y}\cap\left(A\setminus\{x,y\}\right)=\emptyset$. It follows for the choice of $W_{y}$ that $W_{y}\cap \left(A\setminus\{y\}\right)\neq\emptyset$, but then we can conclude that $W_{y}\subset\{x\}$, which is absurd.

Is this a correct proof?

Comment: You cannot prove a false statement.

Comment: True. Which condition do I need to add to make this a true statement? My professor gave me that problem, maybe I forgot an additional assumption.

Comment: $T_1$ is often needed to make limit points behave. I think that would do it here.

Comment: Indeed, I edited the question. Now, is there anything to complain about in my proof?

Comment: YOu don't use $T_1$ while you do need it? I use it explicitly in my proof, case 2: singletons are closed so if $U$ is open so is $U$ minus a singleton.

Comment: Yes, thats's right. I have to think about whre my proof needs the $T_{1}$ assumption. Thanks for your proof.

Comment: You're welcome..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is Sierpiński space $\{0,1\}$ (with $0$ isolated) and $A=\{0\}$ and $x=0$ then $\lim (A) =\{1  \} \neq \emptyset = \lim (A\setminus \{x\})$.

If $X$ is $T_1$, then it does hold (Sierpiński space is merely $T_0$): assuem WLOG that $x \notin A$; if $y \in \lim(A\setminus\{x\})$ every neighbourhood $U$ of $y$ intersects $A\setminus \{x\})$ in a point distinct fom $y$, so in particular in a point of $A$ distinct from $y$, so $y \in \lim(A)$. If $y \in \lim(A)$, let $U$ be an open neighbourhood of $y$. Case 1: $y=x$ and $U$ intersects $A\setminus\{y\}=A\setminus\{x\} = A\setminus\{x,y\}$, which implies $y \in \lim(A\setminus\{x\})$. Case 2: $y \neq x$ and then $U\setminus\{x\}$ is also an open neighbourhood of $y$ by $T_1$-ness and hence intersects $A\setminus \{y\}$, so $U$ intersects $A\setminus\{x,y\}$ and again $y \in \lim(A\setminus\{x\})$. QED.